# Mixing traditional class options and pgfoptions?

Tags: pgfkeys, documentclass-writing, class-options, pgfopts

I am trying to mix pgfopts with more classical options to make a custom class. The idea is that classical options would be here to provide predefined behavior, while pgfopts options would be here to provide more customizable behaviors.

For example, let's say my class have a color option with a predefined "red" option, but also provide a pdfopt way to manually set more customs colors. What I mean is that:

- `\documentclass{myclass}` would be a default behavior
- `\documentclass[red]{myclass}` would provide a usual predefined color theme
- `\documentclass[maincolor = green]{myclass}` would allow users to provide their own colors

---

I tried the following:

```
% CLASS

% Preamble
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2022/10/11]
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}

% Packages
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\RequirePackage{color}

% Pgfoptions
\pgfkeys{
    /myclass/.cd,
    maincolor/.store in = \maincolor,
    maincolor = blue,
}
\ProcessPgfOptions{/myclass}

% Class options
\DeclareOption{red}{\pgfkeyssetvalue{maincolor}{red}}
\ProcessOptions

% Test command
\newcommand{\printcolor}{\textcolor{\maincolor}{\Huge{$\bullet$}}}
```

Which produce the following outputs:

- `\documentclass{myclass}\begin{document}\printcolor\end{document}` `=>` `blue` **[OK]**
- `\documentclass[maincolor = green]{myclass}\begin{document}\printcolor\end{document}` `=>` `green` **[OK]**
- `\documentclass[maincolor = red]{myclass}\begin{document}\printcolor\end{document}` `=>` `red` **[OK]**
- `\documentclass[red]{myclass}\begin{document}\printcolor\end{document}` `=>` `blue` **[PROBLEM]**

The traditional class option does not work.

---

**QUESTION:** How to mix pgfopts and traditional class options in this kind of context in order to provide the flexibility of both predefined behavior with `\documentclass[someoption]{myclass}` and customizable behaviors with `\documentclass[somekey = someoption]{myclass}`

Comment: for a new class, I would look to use latex's new built in key-value option handler rather than pgfopts (see ltnews). But in either case don't declare red as a classic option, declare it as a boolean with default `true` so `[red]` is `[red=true]` and you can then pick up `\ifred` in your class

Comment: @DavidCarlisle or the by far superior `expkv-opt`? :P

Comment: @Skillmon something like that. You were probably thinking of `keyval` though.

Comment: What I just noticed, in case you didn't know `\Huge` doesn't take an argument, it acts as a switch so everything that follows until the end of the group (or until another font size switch) will be `\Huge` (but `\textcolor` creates a group as well, so is fine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to `pgfopts` you can use a `.style` key to let `red` set your `maincolor`, for instance with the following class code:

```
% CLASS

% Preamble
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2022/10/11]
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}

% Packages
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\RequirePackage{color}

% Pgfoptions
\pgfkeys{
    /myclass/.cd,
    maincolor/.store in = \maincolor,
    maincolor = blue,
    red/.style={maincolor=red},
    red/.value forbidden
}
\ProcessPgfOptions{/myclass}

% Test command
\newcommand{\printcolor}{\textcolor{\maincolor}{\Huge{$\bullet$}}}
```

But as David suggested in the comments, it might be a better idea to use a different key=value system. The following uses the kernel commands `\DeclareKeys`, `\SetKeys`, and `\ProcessKeyOptions`:

```
% CLASS

% Preamble
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2022/10/11]
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}

% Packages
\RequirePackage{color}

\DeclareKeys
  {
     maincolor .store = \maincolor
    ,red       .meta:n    = {maincolor=red}
    ,red       .value_forbidden:n = true
  }
\SetKeys{maincolor=blue}
\ProcessKeyOptions

% Test command
\newcommand{\printcolor}{\textcolor{\maincolor}{\Huge{$\bullet$}}}
```

But personally I'd prefer `expkv-opt` (well, I wrote it...). In `expkv` you can define keys not taking a value as such, giving a stronger differentiation than the `.value forbidden` approach supported by `pgfopts` and `DeclareKeys` (though for the most part this isn't very relevant, but in theory you could define completely different behaviour for a key with or without a value this way).

```
% CLASS

% Preamble
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2022/10/11]
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}

% Packages
\RequirePackage{expkv-opt,expkv-def}
\RequirePackage{color}

\ekvdefinekeys{myclass}
  {
      store   maincolor = \maincolor
     ,initial maincolor = blue
     ,nmeta   red       = {maincolor=red}
  }
\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions{myclass}% this does the right thing currently and in the future
%\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{myclass}% due to changes in the kernel this doesn't do everything correct in a class file currently -- it might result in a wrongfully thrown "unused global option" error

% Test command
\newcommand{\printcolor}{\textcolor{\maincolor}{\Huge{$\bullet$}}}
```

Comment: +1 even though it's longer than my answer

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
\pgfkeys{
    /myclass/.cd,
    maincolor/.store in = \maincolor,
    maincolor = blue,
    red/.code = \def\maincolor{red},
    red/.value forbidden
}
```

so declaring `red` as a pgf (not classic) option.

Comment: +1 since you were 16 seconds faster